# Why does array map bring this TypeError: props.msg.map is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

`am trying to get the msg input to a div in MsgComponent but when i try to map through the msg, it bringing an error : MsgComponent.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: props.msg.map is not a function.
the error always come up once i typed into the input area. have checked the props.msg type and it an Array but i dont realy understand why it still flagging the error.

I have look all over google to see what i'm doing wrong. i have tried changing my code in multiple ways but i can't seem to figure out what is wrong. As soon as i click my "send" button, it crashes and gives me the TypeError: props.msg.map is not a function.

```
import React , {useState}from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import {Box, TextField, Paper, IconButton, Button,List, ListItem, ListItemAvatar,ListItemButton,Avatar, ListItemText} from '@mui/material';
import MsgComponent from './MsgComponent';

const Chat= (onIdSubmit)=>{
    const [msg, setMsg]=useState([]);
    const [ismsg, setIsmsg]=useState(true);
    const [btnVal,setBtnval]=useState(true);

   
   const send = ()=>{
         setMsg((prev)=>{
             return(
             [...prev, msg])});
       setIsmsg(false);
       setBtnval(false);
      
   }
   const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
      e.preventDefault();
      onIdSubmit(()=>setMsg(e.target.value));
   }

    return(

        <Box sx={{Color:'blue'}}>
            <Box sx={{ position:'absolute', top:'0%'}}>
            <Header/>
        </Box>
                <Box>
                    <MsgComponent msg = {msg}/>
                </Box>
           
        <Box sx={{position:'absolute', bottom:'1%'}}>
         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <TextField multiline={true} maxRows={31} placeholder='message' value={msg} onChange={(e)=>setMsg(e.target.value)}/>
              <Button onClick={send}>send</Button>
             </form> 
           
          </Box> 
        
        </Box>
    )
}
export default Chat;
```

`this is the MsgComponent,`

```
import React from 'react';

 
const MsgComponent =(props)=>{

   // const{msg} =props;
   const data=props.msg.map((message)=>{
      return({message});
}
   )

return (
 <div>
  {data}
 </div>
 )}
export default MsgComponent;
```

Comment: `setMsg(e.target.value)` is causing the error, `e.target.value` is for sure not an array, it's a string.

Comment: The error mens you are trying to iterate over object that is not an array, make sure that is your msg is array, you might wrapped it under msg.data or msg is undefined

Comment: Really appreciate your contribution.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the `msg` state for two separate things - the `TextField` value (a string), and also the array of strings that have been submitted. Separate them out instead - maybe call one `textFieldValue`, and the other `submittedMessages`.

```
const Chat= (onIdSubmit) => {
    const [textFieldValue, setTextFieldValue] = useState('');
    const [submittedMessages, setSubmittedMessages] = useState([]);
    const send = ()=>{
        setSubmittedMessages([...submittedMessages, textFieldValue]);
        setIsmsg(false);
        setBtnval(false);
   }
```

```
<TextField multiline={true} maxRows={31} placeholder='message' value={textFieldValue} onChange={(e)=>setTextFieldValue(e.target.value)}/>
```

```
<MsgComponent submittedMessages={submittedMessages} />
```

And then iterate over the `submittedMessages` prop in `MsgComponent` properly. (Right now, you're returning an object rather than a string or an element.) Maybe something like

```
const MsgComponent = ({ submittedMessages }) => {
    return (
        <div>
        { submittedMessages.map(message => <span>{message}</span>) }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, the `onIdSubmit` passed to Chat should be a singular prop (not the whole props object).

```
const Chat = ({ onIdSubmit }) => {
```